# Check many conditions in a loop of an array of objects efficiently

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects and one property is their statuses, I need to calculate the status following this:
if all the statuses are failed return "failed", if all are canceled return "canceled", and so on, but if the array has one failed, or one canceled return "partially completed", I did, but I am looping a lot and I feel that exist a better and efficient way to do the same, this is my code:

```
function getComputedStatus(list) {

      if (list.every(status => status.statusName == 'Failed'))
          return 'Failed';

      if (list.every(status => status.statusName == 'Canceled'))
          return 'Canceled';

      if (list.every(status => status.statusName == 'DidNotRun'))
          return 'DidNotRun';

      if (list.some(status => status.statusName == 'InProgress' ||
          status.statusName == 'Pending'))
          return 'InProgress';

      if (list.some(status => status.statusName === 'Failed'   ||
                              status.statusName === 'Canceled' ||
                              status.statusName === 'DidNotRun'))
         return 'PartiallyCompleted';

      return 'Completed';
}
```

Comment: Questions like this really help if you can give some example input data, and expected output.  SO users can then quickly knock up snippets to help,.. IOW: If you help SO users, your likely to get a much better response.

Comment: `var hasFailed = list.includes("Failed"); var hasCanceled = list.includes('Canceled'); ....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it appears that your logic is actually this:

1. You have an array of status objects.
2. If any status is 'InProgress' or 'Pending', then return 'InProgress'
3. If all statuses are the same and are 'Failed', 'Canceled' or 'DidNotRun', then return that value.
4. If any status are 'Failed', 'Canceled' or 'DidNotRun', then return 'PartiallyCompleted'
5. Otherwise, return 'Completed'

So, there would be a huge efficiency of execution gain if you can figure out how to do all these checks with one pass through the array instead of your 5 partial passes through the array.

Here's one way to do that:

```
const doneStatuses = new Set(["Failed", "Canceled", "DidNotRun", "Completed", "InProgress"]);

function getComputedStatus(list) {
    const allStatuses = new Set();

    // collect all status values in a Set object
    for (let status of list) {
        allStatuses.add(status.statusName);
    }

    // if all the statusName values were the same and they were  
    // "Failed", "Canceled", "DidNotRun", "InProgess" or "Completed"
    // then return that specific status
    if (allStatuses.size === 1) {
        let theStatus = Array.from(allStatuses)[0];
        if (doneStatuses.has(theStatus)) {
            return theStatus;
        }
    }
    // if any status was "InProgress" or "Pending", return "InProgress"
    if (allStatuses.has("InProgress") || allStatuses.has("Pending")) {
        return "InProgress";
    }

    // If any status was "Failed", "Canceled" or "DidNotRun" (but not all)
    // then return "PartiallyCompleted"
    if (allStatuses.has("Failed") || allStatuses.has("Canceled") || allStatuses.has("DidNotRun")) {
        return "PartiallyCompleted";
    }

    // otherwise, return "Completed"
    return "Completed";
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can I ask you why you used a Set for allStatuses if the values are unique, fixed and known? What are the advantages over a "plain regular object" (aside for checking being cleaner & shorter, which I think it's awesome so thanks for that!)?

Comment: @EmilioGrisolía - You would use a Set when you have or want unique values and you want to do an efficient lookup on them.  In this case, you could either use the Set with `.has()` or you could use an array with `.includes()`.